# Lucene on Google AppEngine (GAE)

Tags: google-app-engine, lucene

I was trying to use lucene in a GAE application but, with lucene 3.1.0, even using RAMDirectory (which should be ok, I have only about 300 docs to index), I have an error committing or closing the index (see below). Clues?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.lucene.store.IndexOutput.writeString(IndexOutput.java:103)
at org.apache.lucene.store.IndexOutput.writeStringStringMap(IndexOutput.java:221)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfo.write(SegmentInfo.java:619)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.write(SegmentInfos.java:381)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.prepareCommit(SegmentInfos.java:851)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.startCommit(IndexWriter.java:4224)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareCommit(IndexWriter.java:3161)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:3232)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commit(IndexWriter.java:3214)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commit(IndexWriter.java:3198)
```

PS: it of course works on my machine

Comment: Have you tried a specific GAE solution ? Here is a Lucene component designed for GAE: http://code.google.com/p/gaelucene/

Comment: well I need to rebuild the index every 30 minutes with fresh data and gaelucene is readonly. I'm trying lucene-for-gae http://code.google.com/p/lucene-for-gae/ which would fit the requirement but I cannot get it working (I have a "cannot get a write lock on index" error or something like that )

Comment: the write lock error is probably because of the earlier crash. Try deleting the write.lock file and re-running.

Comment: @Xodarap it doesn't make any sense - in GAE you cannot use files directly (hence the error), so there's no file to delete (you see I'm trying to work on RAMDirectory?)

Comment: Have you tried Lucene App Engine? http://code.google.com/p/lucene-appengine There is also a live demo.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten this to work on App Engine a few months ago:

http://ikaisays.com/2010/04/24/lucene-in-memory-search-example-now-updated-for-lucene-3-0-1/

When deploying to App Engine, are you keeping a global reference to a RAMDirectory? This is going to be problematic because you do not have a single JVM - you might have multiple JVMs. Request #1 might go to Instance A, which initializes the in-memory index, but request #2 may go to Instance B (different JVM) that still has a null reference for the index. Could this be what is happening?